# Does get bloginfo work on localhost?

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to use

`<?php $bloginfo = get_bloginfo( $show, $filter ); ?>`

on localhost but does not work for me. Please guide. Thanks

Update:

I know the API usage. I have been using it like,

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo( 'css/style.css' ); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But it does not work(instead of generating the path to the blog theme it displays the website title instead). I suppose its not going to work on localhost and I would have to use absolute paths.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "does not work"?

Comment: What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: "***I know the API usage.***" - I don't think you do, but hey, that's why you're here. :)

Comment: @SpencerCameron: Pardon me. I just saw the reference page again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to work this way, you actually need to pass parameter values in this method to make it work.

To fetch **blog title**, use -

```
<?php $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

For **blog tagline** -

```
<?php echo 'Your Blog Tagline is: ' . get_bloginfo ( 'description' );  ?><br />
```

Check for the parameter listing at -

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)

From your new `edit` -

Use this for stylesheet path -

```
get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url');
```

Consider using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead.